# Which is faster to load in android, a file from external storage or a file from internal storage?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Which is faster to load in android, a file from external storage or a file from internal storage? I am guessing that in many phones like in Motorola Droid the SD Card(flash memory) used for internal and external storage are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to depend on the type of flash memory used internal and the classification of the external SD card. For example if a user has Class 6 SD card the read speed is going to be around 6 MB/second but with only a class 2 (which most devices ship with) is 2 MB/sec.

You shouldn't make any assumptions about the speed of either the internal of external read/write speeds because they will vary per device and per storage quota (how full they are).
Design as generically as possible and make use of [StrictMode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html) to ensure proper thread usage.

Comment: Actually those are the write speeds.  The read speeds tend to be a few times faster, if the data channel to the card can handle it.

Comment: @Chris Stratton Ah yes you are correct. Usually I'm more concerned with write speeds because they are slower than the reads. For those interested Brad Fitzpatrick (wrote StrictMode) did a presentation at Google I/O last year on (partially) this topic of disk speeds. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4znvD-7VDA

Answer (score 3):

I imagine that the internal memory is going to be quicker for the system.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that this depends a lot on the hardware, which includes both the device as well as the SD card. In general, I would expect internal storage to be faster.

As for SD cards, check out the speed ratings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Speed_Class_Rating

Answer (score 0):

if you really need to have the fastest read you can check first via a speedtest, e.g. read 1M from flash and than from sdcard to check whats better for your purpose.